# Use of the word "cork" to signify a mistake?

Tags: slang

A colleague who is a ELL used the word "cork" to signify a mistake/error/typo on a schedule.

> I thought that the four-day schedule was a cork.

She says she thinks her English teacher was a Kiwi. I can't find any such usage.

Comment: Could it have been "cock-up"?

Comment: Was this in writing or in speech? If the latter, is the speaker non-rhotic?

Comment: Where did you look? Providing that information may be useful in helping other people to avoid some unnecessary searching.

Comment: "Crock" is often used in the US to refer to a questionable usage.

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed, and I believe I've also heard it used quite frequently in TV programs originating from Australia, so it's not too much of a stretch to include New Zealand and the "Kiwi" teacher. I also believe that "crock" is probably a shortening of the phrase "crock of shit" AKA chamber pot where "crock" refers to an item made of ceramic .

Comment: @PeterJennings: In BrE, at least, ***an old crock*** means *A worn-out vehicle, ship, etc.* Deriving from ***crock*** = *An old ewe, or one that has ceased bearing* (later, also *An old broken-down horse*). Apparently etymologically unrelated to ***crock*** = *An earthen pot, jar, or other vessel.* Definitions from the full OED.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed, but in the context of the OP's quoted sentence, I think describing the schedule as a load of rubbish is probably nearer the required meaning than calling it old and broken down.

Comment: [Dictionary of Australian slang:](https://australian_slang.en-academic.com/1985/Crock) **Crock** - 1. *nonsense, rubbish;*  2. *worn-out, decrepit old person; a person laid-up by ill health;* 3. *old motor car or boat (from 'crock' - 'old ewe', 'old horse')* I think it's unlikely the Aussies derived the first of those (clearly *semantically* overlapping) senses from a different source to the other one or two. But who knows?

Answer (score 2):

It could have been an intentional abbreviation or a mishearing of **corker**. [NZ English is often non-rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English), so someone from a rhotic background might have been expecting more of an "r" sound at the end.

"I thought that the four-day schedule was a [huge mistake]."

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/corker) has "a person or thing that is especially good, attractive, or funny" and gives the example "She told an absolute corker of a story about a priest she'd mistaken for an ex-lover.". [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corker)'s second definition has "one that is excellent or remarkable".

I've not been able to find any references to "a real cork" being used to refer to something dramatic, but as soon as I type it my search engine prompts for "a real corker", which is an expression I've often heard in casual conversation (UK English).